# I have no idea what is wrong with my for loop, but it doesn't work. Any help would be amazing

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I am writing a for loop that goes through a range of data (fig 1) and pulls out specific rows depending on a set of conditions.
[Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMaKd.png)

Here is my code.

```
function newReport() {
  var date = new Date();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1QAB-9POYxmr_Al4J4IRlGsl4TZ0G9eXCiungZmAx5ng");
  var ss1 = ss.getSheetByName("Main");
  var newSheet = ss.insertSheet();
  var name = Utilities.formatDate(date, 'America/Chicago', 'MM/dd/yy');
  newSheet.setName(name);
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1QAB-9POYxmr_Al4J4IRlGsl4TZ0G9eXCiungZmAx5ng").getSheetByName(name);
  ss2.getRange("A1").setValue("Sales in Past Week").setBackground("LightBlue");
  ss2.getRange("E1").setValue("Back Stock Order").setBackground("LightBlue");
  for (i=1; i<101; i++){
    var type = ss1.getRange("B"+[i+1]).getValue;
    var selection = ss1.getRange("A"+[i+1]+":B"+[i+1]);
    if (type == "ce"){
      if (ss1.getRange("D"+[i+1]).getValue <10){
        ss2.getRange("E"+[i+1]+":F"+[i+1]).setValues(selection);
        var amount = 15 - ss1.getRange("D"+[i+1]).getValue;
        ss2.getRange("G"+[i+1]).setValue(amount);
      }
    }
    else if (type == "HB"){
      if (ss1.getRange("B"+[i+1]).getValue < 3){
        var amount1 = 5 - ss1.getRange("D"+[i+1]).getValue;
        ss2.getRange("E"+[i+1]+":F"+[i+1]).setValues(selection);
        ss2.getRange("G"+[i+1]).setValue(amount1);
      }
    }

    }
  }
```

I want to pull out rows and paste to a new sheet where the Current value is less than a set number. However this set number changes depending on the Type. I feel like I am doing this in a very sub-optimal way but it's the only way I can think of doing it. This is not working at all though, but it also isn't throwing any errors so I don't know how to trouble shoot. I would greatly appreciate a little guidance.

Comment: When you call `getValue`, you should actually be writing `getValue()`. You can greatly improve your code by using [batch operations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations) rather than having all of those individual `getRange()` and `setValue()` calls.

Comment: Please share a sample sheet.